# NeoOffice pay version vs free version

Tags: neooffice

Do you know if there are any features included in NeoOffice from AppStore but not included in the free version? I suppose not, because as OpenOffice is free software, NeoOffice must be too, so they should release their full work for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their website:

> NeoOffice 2014.1 Free Edition has the same features as NeoOffice in Apple's Mac App Store.
>   The only difference is that NeoOffice 2014.1 Free Edition cannot save documents.

The open source license that is used for the NeoOffice source code (GPL) doesn't require that the software be provided for free. It just requires that the source code be made available for free. NeoOffice do offer their source free, but it obviously requires a certain amount of skill and time to compile.

Comment: Then why should anybody buy it?

Comment: Firstly to support the effort that the two developers have put into the project, encouraging/enabling them to continue working on the project, and secondly so that users don't have to download and compile the application themselves. Those are the two reasons that spring to mind right now.

Comment: In their own words: "The cost and time spent on NeoOffice is very large for Patrick and Ed - the Mac software engineers that have created all of the improvements in NeoOffice that are not in OpenOffice. While many free software products such as Firefox and Google Docs are funded by huge payments from large corporations, NeoOffice has no corporate sponsors. Without any corporate sponsors, Patrick and Ed must rely exclusively on payments from our users to continue implementing the latest Mac OS X features in NeoOffice."

Comment: Everyone I know uses LibreOffice these days.